# how do I tunnel through a tunnel?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a SecureLink Enterprise connection at work. This allows to me start a VPN via a web portal which then sets up an ssh tunnel for me to a pre-defined remote machine. After the tunnel is created I am given a random port to connect to that specified remote host through. For example, after I login I am given, say, port 60994. I then, on my local machine, do this:

```
ssh localhost -p 60994 -l my_username
```

and I connect to the remote machine.

Now, I am developing a web application on this host and need to create a tunnel to test things out.
If I want to connect to port 443 on the remote host how do I create an assh tunnel to do that, given the information that I have?

I have tried this

```
ssh -L 60994:localhost:443 my_username@localhost -p 60994
```

But that doesn't work. I can open a shell on the remote host but when I try and go to the https://localhost:60994 in a browser there is no connection.

It seems I want to "tunnel through a tunnel"? How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a different port than the one used to establish the ssh connection.

Use:

```
ssh -L 60995:IP_ADDRESS:443 my_username@localhost -p 60994
```

Where IP_ADDRESS is the IP_ADDRESS of the machine running HTTPS

Then:

```
https://localhost:60995
```

In effect what you are doing it's a "tunnel through a tunnel".

Comment: Wow! Ok, now I really think I am getting someplace. However, when I then try to connect to https://localhost:60995 in my browser I am seeing `channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused` in the shell opened on the remote host. Any idea why that is? Could SecureLink be denying me access to ports it itself doesn't create?

Comment: Try:

ssh -L 60995:IP_ADDRESS:443 my_username@localhost -p 60994

Where IP_ADDRESS is the IP_ADDRESS of the machine running HTTPS

Comment: That's it! Awesome! I now see my web page in my browser when I go to https://localhost:60995. If you post your last comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Ok done, I realized also that you are effectively doing a tunnel inside a tunnel.